# Logger for handling both wide and non-wide strings

Tags: c++

I want a single logging function/macro similar to cout/wcout, but that can take both std::string and std::wstring (and wchar_t, etc) as input. Wide inputs will be converted to utf8 before being sent to the stream. Ideally it would look something like this to use it:

```
logger << utf8str << widestr << std::hex << 84 << " blah " << 1.2 << std::endl;
```

A global overload of operator<< will not work for me, since it collides with other parts of my project.

I'm currently trying to extend std::ostringstream like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
using namespace std;

string WToUTF8(const wstring &wsWide) {
    typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> convert_typeX;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_typeX, wchar_t> converterX;
    return converterX.to_bytes(wsWide);
}

struct CLogStream : public virtual std::ostringstream {
    // Allow wstrings
    CLogStream& operator<< (const wstring& ws) { *this << WToUTF8(ws); return *this; }
    // Log wide string literals (e.g. L"widestr") and c-style wide strings as strings instead of hex pointer address
    CLogStream& operator<< (const wchar_t* p_ws) { *this << WToUTF8(p_ws); return *this; }
    // Log wchar_t as a character instead of a number
    CLogStream& operator<< (const wchar_t wc) { *this << WToUTF8(wstring(&wc,1)); return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    string s("narrow ");
    wstring ws(L"_WIDE_");

    CLogStream log;

    // These seem to work how I want them to
    log << "narrow";
    log << L"_WIDE_";
    log << L"_WIDE_" << "narrow";
    log << ws << L"_WIDE_";
    log << s << "narrow";
    log << ws << "narrow";
    log << ws << s;

    // Here I think maybe the compiler uses the ostream << instead of operator<< I defined for CLogStream...
    log << "narrow" << L"_WIDE"; // outputs wide string as a hex value (pointer to the string)
    //log << s << ws;// won't compile - error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'std::wstring {aka std::basic_string<wchar_t>}')

    cout << log.str();/* output from http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/:
    narrow_WIDE__WIDE_narrow_WIDE__WIDE_narrow narrow_WIDE_narrow_WIDE_narrow narrow0x4026d4*/
}
```

This *almost* works for me, except that when a wide input follows a non-wide *in the same line*, the compiler stops using the operator<< definition that I want it to. Could anyone explain why this is happening? Is there a way to prevent it, or another approach I could use to accomplish my goal?

As suggested, I tried defining the stream operators as non-members:

```
    CLogStream& operator<< (CLogStream& strm, const wstring& ws) { strm << WToUTF8(ws); return strm; }
    CLogStream& operator<< (CLogStream& strm, const wchar_t* p_ws) { strm << WToUTF8(p_ws); return strm; }
    CLogStream& operator<< (CLogStream& strm, const wchar_t wc) { strm << WToUTF8(wstring(&wc,1)); return strm; }
```

but I get the exact same output/compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Here's the solution I ended up using:</strike>

Although this works for strings/wstrings, it **fails** for:

- things like std::endl and other manipulators
- numeric inputs, which based on my output, I think are interpreted as wide characters.

-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
using namespace std;

string WToUTF8(const wstring &wsWide) {
    typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> convert_typeX;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_typeX, wchar_t> converterX;
    return converterX.to_bytes(wsWide);
}

// This part is to avoid globally overloading std::ostringstream's operators,
//  a restriction from elsewhere in my project
struct CLogStream : public virtual std::ostringstream
{   
    CLogStream& operator<< (const wstring& ws) { *this << WToUTF8(ws); return *this; } // Allow wstrings
    CLogStream& operator<< (const wchar_t* p_ws) { *this << WToUTF8(p_ws); return *this; } // c-style wide strings as strings instead of hex pointer address
    CLogStream& operator<< (const wchar_t wc) { *this << WToUTF8(wstring(&wc,1)); return *this; } // wchar_t as a character instead of a number
};

// wrapping the stream prevents the output of CLogStream& operator<< from being interpreted as std::ostringstream
struct CLogger
{
    CLogStream s;
    string str() { return s.str(); }

    template <class T>
    CLogger& operator<<(T&& x) { s << std::forward<T>(x); return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    string s("narrow");
    wstring ws(L"_WIDE_");

    CLogger log;
    log << "narrow" << L"_WIDE" << s << ws; //works
    log << std::hex << 84; //won't compile
    log << std::endl; //won't compile
    log << std::setw(5); //won't compile
    log << "1679.2='" << 1679.2 << "'"; //outputs as character
    log << "534='" << 534 << "'"; //outputs as character

    cout << "log=\n" << log.str() << "done" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>A global overload of operator<< will not work for me, since it collides with other parts of my project.</strike>
Turns out this was false. I didn't look close enough at my "duplicate definition" errors - the real problem was that I defined my << overloads in a common .h file, which was referenced by multiple translation units (so each tu then contained a new (re-)definition). The solution was to 'inline' the definitions in the .h

Had I then encountered an actual definition collision, I could've put the overloads in a namespace, but there were no collisions.